# How do I use the Pigpiod read function within a script

Tags: pigpio, script

Im trying to use the read function from the pigpio library inside of a pigpiod script.
Here is how:

```
detect = pi.store_script('tag 1 inr p0 r4 jp 1 tag 2 r 4 jz 2 tag 3 inr p1 r 4 jp 3 jmp 1')
```

My problem: the jp command does not account the read on gpio 4 as a value in any way and i cant figure out how to alter a parameter or variable according to what "r 4" outputs.
To make things clear: I am trying make my script increase p0 every loop while a Button connected to gpio 4 is pressed and continue with the script after the button has been released. But my script simply doesnt change its outcome if i press the button or if i dont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JP command jumps on greater than or equal to zero.  It's of no use in checking a GPIO level as 0 and 1 are treated the same.

Change JP to JNZ.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. Seems like i was way overthinking and should better have worked on my basic maths. Thank you very much